# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) for React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I get two times this error when i run my app.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "Ankur",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path'),
    DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"),
    SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config ={
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path:DIST_DIR +  "/app",
        filename:"bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                include:SRC_DIR,
                query:
                {
                    presets:["react","es2015","stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

### Index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router";
import {User} from "./components/User";
import {Root} from "./components/Root";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/" component={Root} />
                    <Route path="/user" component={User} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

### Root.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Header} from "./Header"


export class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-10">
                        <Header />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-10">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### User.js

```
import React from 'react'

export class User extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>
                    User Page
                </h3>
                <p>User ID:</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### Header.js

```
import React from "react";

export const Header = (props) => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="navbar-header">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );

};
```

Webpack does not show any error while compiling, Only when the app is run i get an error in the console. There are similar questions in stack overflow tried to follow there suggestions nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using named exports so imports should be

```
import {User} from "./components/User";
import {Root} from "./components/Root";
```

Or change exports to default

```
class User extends React.Component{ ...}

export default User;
```

**UPD**

Also don't you need `react-router-dom` to get `BrowserRouter`

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom"; // not react-router
```

Comment: I have changed in index.js and other places to use import {User} from "./components/User";. the error is still there

Comment: I have done it every where and also updated the question, the error is still there

Comment: You have `User` and `Root` in a folder named `components`?

Comment: installed react-router-dom and the error is gone, thanks for pointing it out.when i run this http://localhost:8080/user  it returns saying 
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Comment: @ankur The latest problem should be asked as a different question I guess. Cause it is likely not related to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Root.js

```
<div className="col-10">
   <header /> /* <---- MUST BE <Header/> */
</div>
```

[image: Edit wqxn9o013w]

Comment: Thanks Sasha, I have corrected this however the error is still there

Comment: Do you have Header.js ?

Comment: Added the header.js file in the question description